# how to group time by 24 hour interval in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to group all rows into a 24-hour(All the rows lie in 1 to 24 which means every row's time interval type(0 to 24) ).
For example, 11:47:43 belong to type 11 and 21:17:43 belong to type 21, and so on.
This is part of my data frame that  I want to group by the 24-hour interval.

[image]

I tried using python group by method but it didn't work for me.This is what I tried.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='24h'))
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear, do you want to group all the rows by the hour values or do you want to simply add a new column indicating the hour of a row?

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem description. Please edit your question to include what happened and why this is not what you expected/wanted.

Comment: @RanikaNisal thanks for your reply. I want to add new column and put each row's time type(group by 0 to 24).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change your time column to a datetime object using

```
import pandas as pd

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Afterwards you can use

```
df['hour_stamp'] = df['time'].dt.hour
```

to extract the number of hours.